# Submit few forms in Drupal 7

Tags: forms, javascript, polls

I try to add  Poll-voting to my website, on page I addet 5 votings forms, I try to make submission of all 5 forms by one click instead of 5 clicking. I wrote this script :

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      function submitDetailsForm() {
           $('#poll-view-voting').submit();
       }
 </script>
```

But this code submit first form only(the forms has one id).
Console.log retrieve this:

```
[form#poll-view-voting, context: document, selector: "#poll-view-voting", init:  function, jquery: "1.4.2", size: function…]
0: form#poll-view-voting
context: documentlength: 1
selector: "#poll-view-voting"
__proto__: Object[0]
```

How i can solve this issue, help please. I am new in Drupal 7 and JS.

Comment: You can't submit more than one form at a time, your browser won't let you. You're also using an ID as a selector, which by definition means you'll only get one element back (unless your markup is wrong). Not 5. It's hard to see how this would have anything to do with Drupal beyond the fact your markup is being generated by Drupal - could you edit the question to confirm why you feel this is a Drupal (and not Javascript) problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use **[Advanced Poll](https://www.drupal.org/project/advpoll)** module. I think this may help you to solve your query.

Comment: i try to use this, but i still have same result. When i create new poll i get single form.